# Unable to upload file using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have the following HTML for file upload.

```
<div class="drop-zone hand-cursor ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" ngf-select="" ngf-drop="" data-ngf-pattern=".pdf" data-ngf-accept="application/pdf" data-ng-model="vm.siteVo.signed_order_form">
    <!-- ngIf: !vm.siteVo.signed_order_form -->
    <div ng-if="!vm.siteVo.signed_order_form" class="ng-scope"><i class="material-icons primary-color font-size-40">backup</i>
        <br><span class="color54 font-size-16 ng-binding">Drag and drop file here or click to open explorer</span></div>
    <!-- end ngIf: !vm.siteVo.signed_order_form -->
    <!-- ngIf: vm.siteVo.signed_order_form -->
</div>
```

I tried the following to locate

`driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".drop-zone > .ng-scope").send_keys("file path")`

but got following error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.90)
```

Comment: The file input is probably a hidden input element somewhere. You'll need to find some `//input[@type='file']` and execute Javascript to reveal it, then send text to the `input` element. You can't send keys to a `div`.

Comment: @Christine  I searched the whole file but unable to find `input` with `type` `file`

Comment: If you post the full page HTML, or provide the URL you are using, we may be able to help better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: The `input` with `type` `file` was not in the same `div` but randomly placed in the page. Located it using xpath and directly used `send_keys()`